# Ansible variable manipulation within vars

Tags: ansible

I want to construct the password (`ansible_ssh_pass`) within the vars section of my playbook from a string passed as an input (`pass_var`). The problem here is that the actual password should be the first 6 characters from the variable (`pass_var`). I am not sure how to achieve it. Here is my playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  user: "{{username}}"
  become: yes
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
     ansible_ssh_pass: <someway to decode string (base64 -d) and get first 6 characters>
```

I'm running the playbook as:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "pass_var=${pass_val} username=${user}"
```

I also need to do some shell manipulations. For example, my string will be base64 encoded, so I need to decode it as well. Something like: `echo ${pass_var} | base64 -d | rev | cut -c1-6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python-style string slicing in Ansible, so you can just write:

```yaml
vars:
  ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ pass_var[:6] }}"
```

For example, the following command:

```
ansible localhost -e pass_var=1234567890 -m debug -a 'msg={{pass_var[:6]}}'
```

Will output:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "123456"
}
```

---

If your initial string is base64 encoded, you can use Ansible's `b64_decode` filter:

```yaml
ansible_pass: "{{ (pass_var|b64decode)[:6] }}"
```

And if for some weird reason you need to reverse it, there is a `reverse` filter:

```yaml
ansible_pass: "{{ ((pass_var|b64decode)|reverse)[:6] }}"
```

If we modify my earlier example, we get:

```
ansible localhost -e pass_var="MTIzNDU2Nzg5MA==" -m debug -a 'msg={{((pass_var|b64decode)|reverse)[:6]}}'
```

Which produces:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "098765"
}
```

Comment: I also need to do some shell manipulations. Like my string will be a base64 encoded string. So I need to decode it as well. Like : echo ${pass_var} | base64 -d | rev | cut -c1-6

Comment: Hello larsks, yes kindly have a second look. Since its an encoded string, I need to decode it as well. I am just trying to figure out how to perform the shell manipulations within the vars section so I get the desired result

Comment: I've updated the answer. I suggest reading through the [Ansible filter documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) as well as the [Jinja filter list](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters).

Comment: That incredible. Really awesome. I was stuck on this for quite a while. I m really grateful for your kind help in resolving the issue

Comment: If this answered your question, you may want to click on the checkmark to the left of this answer.